# Unable to make migrations in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model class in which I have 4 fields. When I am trying to make migrations it's saying:

```
No changes detected
```

Below is my model file:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class CarDetail(models.Model):
   modelname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   modelimg = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'allcars/')
   modelcolor = models.CharField(max_length=11)
   modelage = models.IntegerField()
```

How can I migrate fields to database?

Comment: Did you add the app to `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Yeah I have added my app.

Comment: what if you run `manage.py makemigrations name-of-the-app`?

Comment: It has create model now but its showing only `modelage` filed in my table.

Comment: did you use trailing commas for the other model fields, so for example `modelname =models.CharField(max_length=20),`?

Comment: No i have not look my post

Comment: Maybe, the problem is in the ImageField, if I am not mistaken you must explicitly install Pillow to use it. Try to pip install Pillow and check

Comment: I have installed pillow.